# Count words without LOOPS

Tags: ruby, hash, count, mapreduce, words

I have a question about Ruby:

Given an input string, I need to return a hash, whose keys are words in the string and whose values are the number of times each word appears. IMPORTANT: I must not use for-loops.

Example: "Today is a day, a sunrise"
Output: {'Today'=>1, 'is'=>1, 'a'=>2, 'day' =>1, 'sunrise'=>1}

Can you help me?

Comment: Sounds like it, else why the `for` loops constraint?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
def count_words_without_loops(string)
  res = Hash.new(0)
  string.downcase.scan(/\w+/).map{|word| res[word] = string.downcase.scan(/\b#{word}\b/).size}
  return res
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
h = Hash.new(0)
"Today is a day, a sunrise".scan(/\w+/) do |w|
  h[w] += 1
end

p h # {"Today"=>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>2, "day"=>1, "sunrise"=>1}
```

Comment: Nice :). And .downcase could be squeezed in there if OP had needed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a for-loop constraint, go recursion!
Just don't forget to have a stop condition.

Comment: map/reduce is probably nicer here, and can do very well on multicore computers